# Case insensitive keys for NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios5, nsdictionary

I am trying to utilize incase-sensitive case for JSON response on NSDictionary as sometimes my response keys type varies, some are camel case, some are lowercase or other mixed combination. Is there any built in functionality to check for in-sensitivity case for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered just converting the key to all lowercase before adding it to the dictionary?  Then whenever you do look up a key, just convert it.

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lately I've shared two classes that might suit your needs. They provide case-insensitive operations (named after `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` methods) while keeping the originally inserted keys.

Give it a try:

https://github.com/keeshux/ios-components/tree/master/Components/Utils/KSCIDictionary

Comment: I like that you use a mapping dictionary to preserve the case of the key and also preserve the `log(n)` complexity of the search algorithm.  Most solutions abandon one or the other of those.

Answer (score 5):

The best way would be to set the key for the NSDictionary to be either all lowercase or all uppercase;

For example lets say I have a NSArray of strings. I could get the keyName before I use it and convert it by using the lowercaseString or the uppercaseString

```
NSString *itemName = @"lastName"; 
itemName = [itemName lowercaseString];
```

this will change the string to lastname or if I used uppercaseString it would be LASTNAME

or you can also change the key name when adding to dictionary like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:objectToAdd forKey:[key uppercaseString]];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (NSString *)lowercaseString
```

It's a default NSString method, just do [key lowercaseString] when adding to, or reading from the NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Although all the answers are correct here, I had to utilize this concept all the way when deserializing my data and inserting the keys, to lowercase and everything works like a charm now. Thanks everyone

Comment: For convenience, you could write a `CaseInsensitive[Mutable]Dictionary` subclass of `NS[Mutable]Dictionary`. You would override each method that takes a key as an argument and call the super method using `[key lowercaseString]`. Now your client code remains perfectly readable: it only has to use a `CaseInsensitiveMutableDictionary` instead of an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't need all of the Dictionary methods or properties. I just needed case-insensitive subscript access. I made a custom class (*not* a superclass of NSMutableDictionary) and implemented the methods to allow subscripted access and made those case insensitive:

```
- (id) objectForKeyedSubscript: (NSString *) key {
    NSMutableDictionary *theData = self->data;
    return theData[[key lowercaseString]];
}

- (void) setObject: (id) newValue forKeyedSubscript: (NSString *) key {
    NSMutableDictionary *theData = self->data;
    theData[[key lowercaseString]] = newValue;
}
```

See also:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a subclass of NSString that compares the keys in a way that ignores case (or diacritics etc.).

The advantage is that it keeps the original strings around in the dictionary. It's also useful in any other places where you want stings to compare with other language specific rules.

This method requires, however, that you first convert the keys in the JSON dictionary into instances of this specific string type and place them back into the dictionary. That means it's not an easy way if you create a dictionary from a JSON string.

I've made such a subclass, see https://gist.github.com/tempelmann/0721dc3bc7b39b1eeb7095e2baf34516

See also my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914964/43615).